# ¿Cómo recoger un valor a través de un servidor formado en html y utilizarlo en C en un sistema embebido?

Tags: html, c, variables, embebido

ANTECEDENTES. Tengo un módulo wifi EMW3162. Este módulo tiene una demo, con la que trabajo, que permite generar un servidor o web. Esta web, tiene como página principal, el código html que abajo aparece, el cual se lanza desde el módulo con funciones de C. Para acceder a la web, corriendo el micro, sólo tengo que acceder con la clave de red y puedo ver la tabla que se genera con el código html de abajo, con un móvil o una laptop. **Esto ya lo puedo hacer**, es decir, ya veo que se genera la web, la tabla.

Es decir, que, **básicamente**, quiero utilizar los valores que se introduzcan por la web/servidor, de esta tabla que veo, como si fuera una entrada del micro, para asignarlas a un tipo primitivo en C. Igual que si asignas un valor de entrada (un pin o cualquier registro del micro) a una variable en C.

La página que genera el EMW3162 es la siguiente (dejo la definición que tiene en C):

```
const char systemPage[] = {
<html><head><title>System Setting</title>\r\n
</head>\r\n\
<body>\r\n\
<table border = \"1\" align = \"center\">\r\n\
<tr>\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
SISTEMA DE BALIZAS 1\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
Kasami255\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
Muestras/Ciclo\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
Ciclos/Simbolo\r\n\
</tr>\r\n\
<tr>\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
BALIZA 1\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
elemento 1
<td>\r\n\
elemento 2
<td>\r\n\
elemento 3
</tr>\r\n\
<tr>\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
BALIZA 2\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
elemento 4\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
elemento 5\r\n\
<td>\r\n\
elemento 6\r\n\
</tr>\r\n\
</table>\r\n\
</body></html>\r\n};
```

Los valores se introducirían en cada **elemento** de la tabla, y se daría **OK** en algún botón.

¿Cómo se recoge un valor en html? 
¿Cómo se puede almacenar?
¿Cómo puedo pasar, o parsear este valor a un tipo primitivo de C?

Gracias por vuestra ayuda y perdón si no me he explicado bien antes.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55735/discussion-on-question-by-jotacorp-como-recoger-un-valor-a-traves-de-un-servido).

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, gracias a @Trauma que me ayudó por aquí y también en exclusiva con este tema, además de algún otro compañero.

Voy a hablar concretamente de la demo 4 de este proyecto: (http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:MxchipWNet_Demo_EMW316x_V1.27.7z) que es para la que se ha resuelto la duda para el módulo emw3162, aunque el procedimiento se puede aplicar de la misma forma para otros proyectos en microcontroladores.

Para no introducir complicaciones entre la pregunta y la respuesta, explico lo que quería hacer y lo que he hecho al final:

*Lo que quería hacer: Quería hacer una tabla en la que se pudieran introducir 3 valores por cada nombre "baliza". En la pregunta, hay 6 elementos en los que se debería poder introducir valores y representarse en forma de tabla. Esos son los valores que se parsearán posteriormente.

El problema es que el micro no tiene potencia para representar 6 elementos en una sola página web de esta forma:

```
<p><Input type=\"number\" name=\"MC\" value = \"%c\"/>\r\n\
```

Pongamos que sólo puede representar 3 en una página web. Así que lo hice de otra forma.

*Lo que se ha hecho: Como no podía representar en una misma web 6  (3 de una "baliza" + 3 de otra "baliza"), separé cada baliza haciendo una web para cada una. El micro sí que tiene potencia para 3  por cada página web. Entonces la página principal de ahora muestra:

```
<p><a align = \"center\" href=\"/baliza1.htm\">BALIZA 1</a></p>\r\n\
<p><a align = \"center\" href=\"/baliza2.htm\">BALIZA 2</a></p>\r\n\
```

de tal forma, que cuando se entra a esta web principal, se ven estos 2 hipervínculos. Si pulsamos uno de los dos nos llevarán a cada una de las páginas. Y cada página tendrá:

```
<form action=\"/baliza1.htm\" method=\"post\">\r\n\
<p><Input type=\"number\" name=\"**VARIABLE1_HTML**\" value = \"%c\"/>\r\n\
<p><Input type=\"number\" name=\"**VARIABLE2_HTML**\" value = \"%c\"/>\r\n\
<p><Input type=\"number\" name=\"**VARIABLE3_HTML**\" value = \"%c\"/>\r\n\
<INPUT type=\"submit\" name=\"botonokeyb\" value=\"OK\">\
</FORM>\r\n\
```

Lo importante que vemos aquí, es que cada página web tiene un tipo "post" y 3 entradas/variables en html con un submit, estas 3 entradas son las que nos permitirán recoger los valores para parsearlos y tratarlos en C.

Bien. Luego, para comprobar que, efectivamente estamos en un tipo post o un get, en este proyecto, para comprobar el tipo que se introduce en una web de un micro, debe de haber una discriminación entre estos tipos get y post. En este caso, hay una función de esta forma:

```
static void HandleHttpClient(int index){

...
...

    if(!strcmp(httpToken.pToken1, "GET")){

...para manejarse con tipo GET

     else if(!strcmp(httpToken.pToken1, "POST")){//PARA MANEJARSE CON EL TIPO POST

       if(!strncmp(httpToken.pToken2, "/baliza1.htm", strlen("/baliza1.htm")))  {   //¿SE ENTRA EN LA BALIZA 1?
         get_settings_param(index, httpToken.pToken2, NumOfBytes - (httpToken.pToken2-httpRequest),1);
    } 
       if(!strncmp(httpToken.pToken2, "/baliza2.htm", strlen("/baliza2.htm")))  {//¿SE ENTRA EN LA BALIZA 2?
         get_settings_param(index, httpToken.pToken2, NumOfBytes - (httpToken.pToken2-httpRequest),2);
    }
```

(Después se comenta para qué sirve get_settings_param).
Básicamente se discrimina entre POST y GET y se vuelve a discriminar entre cual de las webs se ha requerido: baliza1.htm o baliza2.htm. Cada web tiene sus 3 "

Por último y lo más importante. Este código tiene una función que se llama PostParse(). Esta función compara cadenas de caracteres de código html, incluidas nuestras variables/entradas web en html (VARIABLE1_HTML, VARIABLE2_HTML, VARIABLE3_HTML) y devuelve un valor en C.

```
static void get_settings_param(int index, char *postdata, int len, char numero_baliza){
char* pToken1, *pValue;
pToken1  = postdata;    
PostParse(&pToken1,"**VARIABLE1_HTML**",&pValue);
elemento1 = *pValue;
PostParse(&pToken1,"**VARIABLE2_HTML**",&pValue);
elemento2 = *pValue;
PostParse(&pToken1,"**VARIABLE3_HTML**",&pValue);
elemento3 = *pValue;    
}
```

Se ha creado la función get_settings_param() que, entre otras cosas, lo más importante que hace es, recoger el valor "elementox" que serán los valores que buscamos.

Estos valores elementox, son finalmente los mismos valores que introduzcamos por nuestra web para tratarlos con C, de esta forma, se puede variar, en tiempo real, los parámetros que permita y se quiera de un microcontrolador.

Nota: la función PostParse la dejo a continuación. Sinceramente, no se, a nivel interno qué hace, no necesito saberlo. Sé que analiza código html, encuentra la cadena "VARIABLEX_HTML" y el valor que tiene esa cadena, lo devuelve como un unsigned char en C.

```
static u8 PostParse(char** ppStr, const char* pFlag, char** ppValue){
    char* pch=strstr(*ppStr, pFlag);
    char* pch2=NULL;
    if(pch)     {
        pch2=strchr(pch, '=');
        if(!pch2) return FALSE;
        pch2++;
        *ppValue=pch2;
        if(!*ppValue) return FALSE;
        pch=strchr(pch2, '&');
        if(pch) {
            *pch='\0';
            html_decode(pch2, strlen(pch2));
            *ppStr=pch+1;
            return TRUE;}}
    return FALSE;}
```

Nota2: la generación de las páginas web creo que es a parte de este tema y por no complicarlo más, no lo explico.

Nota 3: al principio hablaba, también, del carácter general de recoger una variable, como entrada, de forma genérica.
Para un micro que contiene/genera un servidor web, siempre que se quiera recoger un valor y tratarlo en C se debe tener:

*Discriminación entre los tipos de entrada a través de la página web (Get, post).

*Función para analizar y parsear una cadena de caracteres concreta html y devolver su equivalente en C.
Es por esto que hablaba de poder aplicarlo a otros proyectos.